# Materialize Dynamic Drop Down for Create View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, materialize

I am currently trying to use the Materialize Sass framework to implement a drop down menu for a collection that is dynamic it gets objects added it to it by people creating new tea brands. They are then added to the collection_select to be selected when they are adding a specific tea blend to a created brand. Below is my snippet for my collection.

```rb
 <p> Select a Brand that already exists: </p>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
   <%= f.collection_select :brand_id, Brand.all, :id, :name %>

 </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem and what is your current output?

Comment: I think you need to trigger a change on the dropdown to repopulate it with the data, essentially reloading it.

Comment: I think I may not have been clear my dropdown works already on its own. But I am using the materialize framework to style my pages but currently with materialize-sass working it does not display my dropdown at all